# Calculate mean difference by group

Tags: r

Please excuse me if this is a very trivial question; I am new to R. Say I have this dataset:

```
data
    puppy Measurement_Year Weight
1   Bella             1991    1.0
2   Bella             1993    1.2
3   Bella             1998    7.0
4 Charlie             1997    2.0
5 Charlie             1998    2.5
6  Cooper             1998   12.0
```

…and I am  trying to determine whether the mean weight of the puppies increased or decreased from the first year they were weighed to the last.

Manually, I would say: in their first year of weighing, Bella weighed 1Kg, Charlie 2 kg, and Copper 12 kg. This means their mean weight in the **first year** was: (1 + 2 + 12)/3 = **5 kg**

In the final year of weighing, Bella weighed 7 kg, Charlie 2.5 kg, and Cooper 12 kg. This means their mean weight in the **final year** was : (7 + 2.5 + 12)/3 = **7.2 kg**

This means the mean weight of the puppies **increased by 2.2 kg** that is from 5 kg to 7.2 kg.

I figure that in R, maybe I need to use **group_by**

```
data2 <- data %>% group_by(puppy) %>% summarise(
  weight = mean(Weight)
)
```

From here, I can’t seem to wrap my head around this. I would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `arrange` the data by  `Measurement_Year`, keep `first` and `last` `Weight` and subtract it's `mean` value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(puppy, Measurement_Year) %>%
  group_by(puppy) %>%
  summarise(first = first(Weight), 
            last = last(Weight)) %>%
  summarise(diff_weigth = mean(last) - mean(first))

#  diff_weigth
#        <dbl>
#1        2.17
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp=do.call(rbind,
  by(df,list(df$puppy),function(x){
    data.frame(
      "start"=head(x$Weight,1),
      "end"=tail(x$Weight,1)
    )
  })
)

mean(tmp$end)-mean(tmp$start)

[1] 2.166667
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.